# Solution of a Diophantine equation involving powers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it possible to show that, given $n$, there are infinite values of $k$ giving solutions of the equation:
$$x^n+ky^n=z^n$$
with $k,x,y,z,n$ natural numbers? 
The constrains are: $$2\lt n, 1\lt k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=y=2$, or more generally $x=y=a$. Find suitable values of $k$.